# Ioc and DI where and why

Tags: dependency-injection, inversion-of-control

I am pretty new to IoC and DI, and I cant seem to find the exact scenarios where I should NOT use it.

It make sense to use it at places where I know there is a chance of extension like logging (file-based logging, database logging, etc.) or using data-source (test, production etc).

But what I am confused about is, I can have hundreds of classes in a big project should I use IoC/DI for all of them, does it make code-management/maintaining/unit-testing easy? Does it only helps SoC for such classes?

Similarly, If I know for sure that a class will always create another class's object for example a customer will always have an address, in such cases should I use DI? Will it be a bad practice not to use DI in such cases?

We are about to start a big project using ASP.Net MVC3, is Unity a good choice?

Thanks,
Ali

Answer (score 0):

One thing to note when talking about IoC, we talk about dependencies between objects, not classes. If you are thinking `I need that object, and I need it now!`, this is a good candidate for DI. It will feel natural to pass it as a constructor parameter to your class.